# Рекурсивная функция для вычисления "детей"

Tags: рекурсия, php

Друзья, голова совсем не варит. Понимаю что можно сделать, но не могу придумать как.

```
Есть массив:

    [id]=>parent
    id - объект
    parent - его родитель

    например:
    [1]=>0
    [2]=>1
    [3]=>2
    [4]=>1
    [5]=>1
    [6]=>3
    [7]=>6
    [8]=>7
```

Как вычислить количество детей на каждом уровне?
Понимаю что нужно делать рекурсивную функцию.
Может у кого есть готовая?

```
Тут получается так:
на 0 уровне 1
на 1 уровне 1
на 2 уровне 3
на всех оставшихся по 1
```

Вот код который я сделал, для вычисления детей, внуков, правнуков, праправнуков.
Но он дает мне только 4 уровня. Вопрос, как принципиально составить функцию так, чтобы получить ВСЕ уровни наследования.

```
$qForChildrens=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `clientCards`");
    while($aForChildrens=$qForChildrens->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $cl[$aForChildrens['Id']]=$aForChildrens['father'];
    }

    foreach($cl as $k=>$v){
    $childrens[$v]['children'][]=$k;
    }

    foreach($childrens as $k=>$v){  // внуки
    $childrens[$k]['prachildren']=array();
        if(isset($v['children'] )){
            foreach($v['children'] as $i=>$ch){
                if(isset($childrens[$ch]['children'])){
                    foreach($childrens[$ch]['children'] as $a=>$b){
                    $childrens[$k]['prachildren'][]=$b;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($childrens as $k=>$v){  // правнуки
    $childrens[$k]['praprachildren']=array();
            if(isset($v['prachildren'] )){
                foreach($v['prachildren'] as $i=>$ch){
                    if(isset($childrens[$ch]['children'])){
                        foreach($childrens[$ch]['children'] as $a=>$b){
                        $childrens[$k]['praprachildren'][]=$b;
                        }
                    }   
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($childrens as $k=>$v){  // праправнуки
    $childrens[$k]['prapraprachildren']=array();
        if(isset($v['praprachildren'] )){
            foreach($v['praprachildren'] as $i=>$ch){
                if(isset($childrens[$ch]['children'])){ 
                    foreach($childrens[$ch]['children'] as $a=>$b){
                    $childrens[$k]['prapraprachildren'][]=$b;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Андрей Суржиков, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @eicto дополнил вопрос, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Что-то вы запутали со своими чилдренами и прачилдренами, поэтому не уверен в своем подходе, но может такой вариант сгодится:

    // $arr - исходный массив
    $parents_key = array_unique(array_values($arr));
    $tree = array();
    foreach($parents_key as $p){
        foreach($arr as $k => $v){
            if($v == $p) $tree[$p][] = $k;
        }
    }

[Смотрим результат][1] того, что получим в итоге.

   [1]:http://ideone.com/bR4hhq